# grouping a list in individual lists in a base list or completely individual in maya python

Tags: python, grouping, maya

i have a dynamic group:
for example we have a list with 20 items in it in this time....
i wanna make this list in 4 individual list with 5 items
something like this is in my head..

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
z = len(a)/4
b = []
for i in range(z)
```

and after i don't know what i should do.......

i did something like this but it's completely wrong:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(z):
        b.append(a)
```

this is my codes:

```
import maya.cmds as cm
import random as random
myList = cm.ls(sl = True)
random.shuffle(myList)
b = [myList[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(myList), 5)]
for i in b:
    print str(i)+".v"
```

the result is:

```
[u'curve13', u'curve26', u'curve5', u'curve40', u'curve17'].v
```

but i need:

```
[u'curve13.v', u'curve26.v', u'curve5.v', u'curve40.v', u'curve17.v'].v
```

Comment: If you print `i` and `j` you can probably see why that's not working. And perhaps correct it. It might not be pythonic, but a good exercise nonetheless.

Comment: _"i wanna make this list in 4 individual list with 5 items"_. Please be more specific. Which items go in which lists? Show us what output you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [slice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) operation:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
>>> b = [a[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(a), 5)]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]]
>>> b[2][3]
14
```

---

**UPDATE** response to comment

*access items*

```
>>> for item in b[2]: print '{}.v'.format(item)
...
11.v
12.v
13.v
14.v
15.v
```

**UPDATE2**

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
>>> n = len(a)
>>> b = [a[n*i/4:n*(i+1)/4] for i in range(4)]
>>> c, d, e, f = b
>>> c
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> d
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> e
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
>>> f
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

Comment: could you explain to me what does this part do?                          for i in range(0, len(a), 5)                                                        what does exactly (0,len(a),5)

Comment: and how can i make that list like this:  b = [1,2,3,4,5] , c = [6,7,8,9,10] and so forth

Comment: @iran, In `range(0, 20, 5)`. `0` is start value, `20` is stop value (exlusive). `5` is step. `range(0, 20, 5)` yields `[0, 5, 10, 15]`.

Comment: @iran, Why do you want to make separated variables instead of list of list? Normally such thing is not required. What do you want to really do?

Comment: i can't access to items in list.i'm scripting in maya

Comment: @iran, You can access items as `b[..][..]`. For example, `b[2][3]` yield 14.

Comment: when i do this to my list:

    for i in b:
     print str(i)+".v"

it does this:

        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].v
i wanna do this:

        [1.v,2.v,3.v,4.v,5.v]  how can i have access to each item?

Comment: @iran, I don't understand ...  Do you want print all items?

Comment: @iran, I added an example code that access third group(`[2]`) items.

Comment: i'll add something in my question

Comment: i always want to divide myList by 4

Comment: @iran, Hmm.. See **UPDATE2**.